# Script de módulo logging: usando os.getenv

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estou aprendendo Python e estou seguindo o livro A byte of python. Em um exercício falando sobre o módulo logging há a seguinte linha de código:

```
if platform.system().startswith('Windows'):
logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('DIRETORIOINICIAL'), os.getenv('PATH'), 'test.log')
```

O script apenas escreve dentro do arquivo `teste.log` com o data e hora em que foi rodado o script.

Segui exatamente como está no livro mas recebo sempre o mesmo trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "using_logging.py", line 6, in <module>
    logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('DIRETÓRIOINICIAL'), os.getenv('PATH'), 'test.log')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 108, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ntpath.py", line 159, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Ele não retorna e nem escreve o arquivo.

Comment: Que problema está ocorrendo?

Comment: O trackback retorna esse erro mas não cria o arquivo e nem escreve. Eu troco o `('DIRETÓRIOINICIAL')` por um caminho completo? Mas pelo o que eu entendi o doc diz que `os.getenv` pega a variável do ambiente então eu não precisaria certo?

Comment: Teste `os.getenv('DIRETÓRIOINICIAL')` e veja se retorna algum resultado.

Comment: `None`, então provavelmente o problema é que meu diretório inicial não esta setado é isso?

Comment: Correto, pra falar a verdade essa `'DIRETÓRIOINICIAL'` deveria existir nas sua variáveis de ambiente do Windows, reveja o exemplo utilizado está parecendo uma tradução.

Comment: Mesmo setando `%HomeDrive%` mostra ainda `None`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35823/discussion-between-theo-oliveira-and-rubstackoverflow).